# Open a file with a variable

Tags: python, file

I'm trying to open a file based on an input that the user enters.

This is the code I have right now, but it always seems to go straight to the except block, even when I input the right file name.

```
filename = input("Enter a filename: ")

try:
    open(filename.txt, "w")
    print("Succesfully opened", filename,".txt")

except:
    print("File cannot be found.")
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Hint: Take out the try/except so you can see what error you're actually getting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This will work.

```
filename = input("Enter a filename: ")

try:
    # Access filename as a variable
    open(filename + ".txt", "w")
    print("Succesfully opened", filename,".txt")

# Catch the specific exception
except IOError:
    print("File cannot be found.")
```

Answer (score 2):

change `open(filename.txt, "w")` to `open(filename + '.txt', "w")`

Answer (score -1):

As marked by @Bharel, this will work:

```
filename = input("Enter a filename: ")

try:
    open(filename + ".txt", "w")
    print("Succesfully opened", filename,".txt")

except:
    print("File cannot be found.")
```

The problem was in `open(filename.txt, "w")`, as .txt wasn't a string, so the easiest solution is to concatenate the filename with the extension.